How to override input function in yii2\helpers\BaseHtml from vendor file
I need to make some custom changes to the yii2\helpers\BaseHtml file in Yii2. Is there any way to make these custom changes without modifying the vendor file directly? I specifically need to make changes to a certain function.
public static function input($type, $name = null, $value = null, $options = []) {
    if (!isset($options['type'])) {
       $options['type'] = $type;
    }
        
     $options['name'] = $name;
     $options['value'] = $value === null ? null : (string) $value;
     return static::tag('input', '', $options);
}

Custom changes must be do in out of the vendor files

It kind of depends what exactly are you trying to achieve. Most reasonable thing to do would be creating own helper that would extend yii2\helpers\Html and override the input() method there. Then use your helper instead of yii2\helpers\Html in your code.

I agree with @MichalHynčica that's is a an entire principle of the PHP you can overwrite any class, just think and have a good clue what and how to to this.
